# Python linking 2 strings

Tags: python

I am  working on python program where the goal is to create a tool that takes the first word word from a file and put it beside another line in a different file.

This is the code snippet:

```
lines = open("x.txt", "r").readlines()
lines2 = open("c.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in lines:
    r = line.split()
    line1 = str(r[0])
    for line2 in lines2:
        l2 = line2
    rn = open("b.txt", "r").read()
    os = open("b.txt", "w").write(rn + line1+ "\t" + l2)
```

but it doesn't work correctly.

My question is that I want to make this tool to take the first word from a file, and put it beside a line in from another file for all lines in the file.

For example:

File: 1.txt :

```
hello there
hi there
```

File: 2.txt :

```
michal smith
takawa sama
```

I want the result to be :

Output:

```
hello michal smith
hi takaua sama
```

Comment: That is not how nested loops work. You're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): `for a,b in zip(lines, lines2):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the zip function, you can loop through both simultaneously. Then you can pull the first word from your greeting and add it to the name to write to the file.

```
greetings = open("x.txt", "r").readlines()
names = open("c.txt", "r").readlines()

with open("b.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for greeting, name in zip(greetings, names):
        greeting = greeting.split(" ")[0]
        output = "{0} {1}\n".format(greeting, name)
        output_file.write(output)
```

Comment: when i linked them together, the arabic language texts have changed into chinese texts , why is that ??

Comment: That sounds like a unicode problem, not a zip problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , like Tigerhawk indicated you want to use `zip` function, which combines elements from different iterables at the same index to create a list of tuples (each ith tuple having elements from ith index from each list).

Example code -

```
lines = open("x.txt", "r").readlines()
lines2 = open("c.txt", "r").readlines()
newlines = ["{} {}".format(x.split()[0] , y) for x, y in zip(lines,lines2)]
with open("b.txt", "w") as opfile:
    opfile.write(newlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import *

with open('x.txt', 'r') as lines:
    with open('c.txt', 'r') as lines2:
        with open('b.txt', 'w') as result:
            words = imap(lambda x: str(x.split()[0]), lines)
            results = izip(words, lines2)
            for word, line in results:
                result_line = '{0} {1}'.format(word, line)
                result.write(result_line)
```

This code will work without loading files into memory.